# Using one loop to print out two data structures using Iterator pattern java

Tags: java, design-patterns, iterator, while-loop

I have a program that holds data about Students from two colleges, the liberal arts college and the Tech college of some school. the LA college uses an ArrayList in its class and the Tech college uses and array in its class to holds the students. I have implemented the Iterator Pattern (with my own iterator) into this program and therefore have a an Iterator interface plus one concrete iterator for the LAStudents class and one for the TechStudents class. I have implemented the next() and hasNext() methods. There is also an interface class for the student classes called Students that defines the createIterator() method and read() method. The program gets data about students from a text file like so:

```
    TechStudents.txt:
    Smith William CompSci Tech 90 90 340
    Jones Michael CompEnr Tech 45 45 100
    Carter Mary SoftEng Tech 128 124 270
    Harris Harry CompSci Tech 30 30 90
    Wilson Brian CompSci Tech 90 90 270
    Adams Susan CompEng Tech 12 12 45
    Washington George SoftEng Tech 96 96 360
    Jackson Andrew SoftEng Tech 62 60 145
    Madison James CompSci Tech 78 76 120
    Monroe Alicia CompSci Tech 87 87 256
```

There is a similar file with students attending the LAcollege. What I need to do is to print out all the students, both the ones in the array and the ones in the ArrayList, and do it in just **one loop**. Furthermore, I need to **sort** the students by last name in the output. and this is where I am stuck. I realize that i need a Comparator or perhaps a Comparable class, but I don't know which is right and what is the best solution to the problem. Yes, *this is homework but I'm not trying to cut corners*, i just want some help so I can better understand how to program the solution. Afterall, it is an OO class.

Here is the StudentData class that holds data about students. I have added a compareTo() method and a toString() (In addition to the code I was supplied with initially).

public class StudentData{

```
private String LastName, FirstName;
private String Major;
private String College;
private int CreditHoursAttempted;
private int CreditHoursEarned;
private int QualityPoints;

public StudentData(String ln, String fn, String mj, String col,
        int cha, int che, int qp) {
    LastName = ln;
    FirstName = fn;
    Major = mj;
    College = col;
    CreditHoursAttempted = cha;
    CreditHoursEarned = che;
    QualityPoints = qp;
}

public String GetName() {
    return LastName + ", " + FirstName;
}

public String GetCollege() {
    return College;
}

public String GetMajor() {
    return Major;
}

public int GetCreditHoursAttempted() {
    return CreditHoursAttempted;
}

public int GetCreditHoursEarned() {
    return CreditHoursEarned;
}

public int GetQualityPoints() {
    return QualityPoints;
}

public int GPA() {
    return QualityPoints / CreditHoursAttempted;
}

public int compareTo(StudentData other){
    return this.LastName.compareTo(other.LastName);  
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String s = GetName() + " " + College + " " +  Major + " " + GPA();
    return s;
}
```

}

The following is the class in which I call the read() methods from the student classes and then iterate over the two data structures and print the output:

public class ProcessStudents {

```
Students la = new LAStudents();
Students tech = new TechStudents();
StudentsIterator laItr = la.createIterator();
StudentsIterator techItr = tech.createIterator();

public void readAll() throws IOException {
    la.read();
    tech.read();
}

public void print() {

    while (laItr.hasNext() && techItr.hasNext()) {
        StudentData laStudent = (StudentData) laItr.next();
        StudentData techStudent = (StudentData) techItr.next();
        System.out.println(techStudent);
        System.out.println(laStudent);
    }
}
```

}

I have tried sorting using the compareTo() method but it doesn't work out. I have also tried sorting both student lists into one final list and then print that instead, but I can't figure that out either, also it seems to me like it defeats the purpose of using the Iterator Pattern.

I think the above information and code should suffice in assessing how I can solve this problem. Comments on adherence to OO principles and structure are also welcome.

Thanks

Comment: how did you solve? if it was non-trivial, add your own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the solution below to the incomplete version above. This was the final solution I submitted:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 *
 * @author Philip Skogsberg
 */
public class ProcessStudents {

    Students la = new LAStudents();
    TechStudents tech = new TechStudents();
    StudentsIterator laItr = la.createIterator();
    StudentsIterator techItr = tech.createIterator();

    public void readAll() throws IOException {
        la.read();
        tech.read();
    }

    public void print() {
        ArrayList<StudentData> printList = new ArrayList();
        while (laItr.hasNext() && techItr.hasNext()) {
            StudentData laStudent = (StudentData) laItr.next();
            StudentData techStudent = (StudentData) techItr.next();
            printList.add(laStudent);
            printList.add(techStudent);
            if (laItr.isLast() || techItr.isLast()) {
                Collections.sort(printList);
                for (StudentData s : printList) 
                    System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```